# Cast String to Long in SpringEL expression for th select

Tags: html, casting, thymeleaf, spring-el

I am using an object's ID being in a list to decide if it should be selected, like so:

`<option th:each="tag : ${tagList}" th:value="${tag.id}" th:text="${tag.text}" th:selected="${idSet.contains(tag.id)}"></option>`

However, I have to specially create the idSet (`Set<Long>`), as my original implementations, using an existing `Set<String>`:

`<option th:each="tag : ${tagList}" th:value="${tag.id}" th:text="${tag.text}" th:selected="${searchSet.contains(Long.valueOf(tag.id))}"></option>`

OR

`<option th:each="tag : ${tagList}" th:value="${tag.id}" th:text="${tag.text}" th:selected="${searchSet.contains(Long.parseLong(tag.id))}"></option>`

Yielded this exception:

`Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1011E: Method call: Attempted to call method valueOf(java.lang.Long) on null context object`

How do I use my existing set of strings with a long in a SpringEL expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The special 'T' operator can be used to specify an instance of java.lang.Class (the 'type'). **Static methods are invoked using this operator as well**

`parseLong(String)` is a static method of `Long`

So this should work

```
T(Long).parseLong(...)
```

Comment: I had the cast direction wrong; this worked: `th:selected="${searchSet.contains(T(Long).toString(tag.id))}"`

Answer (score 0):

It may just be cleaner to provide a `Set` of `Long` values to the view.  You can unit test, cache, and keep the view simpler.

```
Set<Long> longSet = setOfStrings.stream() 
                                .map(s -> Long.parseLong(s)) 
                                .collect(Collectors.toSet()); 

model.addAttribute("searchSet", longSet);
```

Otherwise, you can parse the strings statically using the `T` operator for Spring (or create a bean utility for Java, but that may be overkill).